# How to test functions in component with enzyme, jest, recompose, react

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs, recompose

Ok, so I'm a little stumped on how to test my component's functionality using enzyme/jest. Still learning how to test my components - I can write simple tests but now I need to make them more complex.

I'd like to know the best way to test that my component's functions are being called properly and that they update state props as they're supposed to. What I'm finding is tricky is that my functions and state all live in my component's props.

If I need to use a spy I'd like to preferably know how to with Jest, but if a dep like Sinon or Jasmine is better suited for the job I'm open to it (just let me know why so I can better understand).

As an example, I have a **UserDetails** component

```
const UserDetails = ({
 userInfo,
 onUserInfoUpdate,
 className,
 error,
 title,
 primaryBtnTitle,
 submit,
 secondaryBtnTitle,
 secondaryBtnFunc,
 ...props
}) => (
 <div className={className}>
   <div className="user-details-body">
     <Section title="User details">
       <TextInput
         className="firstName"
         caption="First Name"
         value={userInfo.first}
         onChange={onUserInfoUpdate('first')}
         name="first-name"
         min="1"
         max="30"
         autoComplete="first-name"
       />
       <TextInput
         className="lastName"
         caption="Last Name"
         value={userInfo.last}
         onChange={onUserInfoUpdate('last')}
         name="last-name"
         min="1"
         max="30"
         autoComplete="last-name"
       />
     </Section>
   </div>

   <div className="errorBar">
     {error && <Alert type="danger">{error}</Alert>}
   </div>

   <ActionBar>
     <ButtonGroup>
       <Button type="secondary" onClick={secondaryBtnFunc}>
         {secondaryBtnTitle}
       </Button>
       <Button type="primary" onClick={submit}>
         {primaryBtnTitle}
       </Button>
     </ButtonGroup>
   </ActionBar>
 </div>
```

**TextInput** consists of:

```
<label className={className}>
 {Boolean(caption) && <Caption>{caption}</Caption>}
 <div className="innerContainer">
   <input value={value} onChange={updateValue} type={type} {...rest} />     
 </div>
</label>
```

Here is example code of my **index.js** file that composes my withState and withHandlers to my Component:

```
import UserDetails from './UserDetails'
import { withState, withHandlers, compose } from 'recompose'

export default compose(
  withState('error', 'updateError', ''),
  withState('userInfo', 'updateUserInfo', {
    first: '',
    last: '',
  }),
  withHandlers({
    onUserInfoUpdate: ({ userInfo, updateUserInfo }) => key => e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      updateCardInfo({
        ...cardInfo,
        [key]: e.target.value,
      })
    },
    submit: ({ userInfo, submitUserInfo }) => key => e => {
      e.preventDefault()
      submitUserInfo(userInfo) 
      //submitUserInfo is a graphQL mutation
      })
    }  
  }) 
)
```

So far, my **test** file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme' 
import UserDetails from './'
import BareUserDetails from './UserDetails'

describe('UserDetails handlers', () => {
  let tree, bareTree

  beforeEach(() => {
    tree = mount(
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <UserDetails />
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
    bareTree = tree.find(BareUserDetails)
  })

  it('finds BareUserDetails props', () => {
    console.log(bareTree.props())
    console.log(bareTree.props().userInfo)
    console.log(bareTree.find('label.firstName').find('input').props())
  })

})
```

the console logs return me the right information in regards what I expect to see when I call on them:

```
//console.log(bareTree.props())
   { error: '',
      updateError: [Function],
      userInfo: { first: '', last: '' },
      updateUserInfo: [Function],
      onUserInfoUpdate: [Function] }

//console.log(bareTree.props().userInfo)
   { first: '', last: '' }

//console.log(bareTree.find('label.firstName').find('input).props()
   { value: '',
      onChange: [Function],
      type: 'text',
      name: 'first-name',
      min: '1',
      max: '30',
      autoComplete: 'first-name' }
```

Now the question is how I can use them, and the best way. Do I even use my functions or do I just check to see that onChange was called?

### UPDATE (sort of)

I've tried this and I get the following:

```
  it('Input element updates userInfo with name onChange in FirstName input', () => {
    const firstNameInput = bareTree.find('label.firstName').find('input)
    ccNameInput.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'John'}})
    expect(ccNameInput.prop('onChange')).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

In my terminal I get:

```
 expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function anonymous]
```

If I try and create a spyOn with Jest, however, I get an error that it cannot read the function of 'undefined'.

I've tried `spy = jest.spyOn(UserDetails.prototypes, 'onUpdateUserInfo')` and `spy = jest.spyOn(BareUserDetails.prototypes, 'onUpdateUserInfo')` and they both throw the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should probably test the dumb component (UserDetails) and HOC separately. For the dumb component you want to render the component with `shallow` and inject the props. To mock the onUserInfoUpdate, you need to do `const onUserInfoUpdate = jest.fn();`

You want something along the lines of ....

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme' 
import UserDetails from './UserDetails'

const onUserInfoUpdate = jest.fn(); // spy
const props = {
  onUserInfoUpdate,
  // list all your other props and assign them mock values
};

describe('UserDetails', () => {
  let tree;

  beforeAll(() => {
    tree = shallow(<UserDetails {...props} />)
  });

  it('should invoke the onUserInfoUpdate method', () => {
    const firstNameInput = tree.find('label.firstName').find('input');
    firstNameInput.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'John' } });

    expect(onUserInfoUpdate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('first');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for our response! I've tried this out and so far it's ok - only issue is when I try to use the onChange prop that is attached to my TextInput component. I can place the props inside of my dumb component UserDetails but TextInput does not pick up those props, which is needs in order for the onChange to be called in the input. Currently I am receiving a message that onChange isn't defined.

Comment: What happens when you do `tree.find('TextInput').length`? You should get 2.

Comment: It is found with a length of two (with two TextInputs in my UserDetalis component). When I check the props, onChange is undefined.

Comment: `onChange` is not a prop AFAIK, it's an event. What you want to do is simulate a change event on the first `TextInput`. `tree.find('TextInput').simulate(change, , { target: { value: 'John' } })`. Just make sure you've passed in all the props.

Comment: You're right, onChange is an event. What I didn't mention before is that instead of `shallow` I used `mount` because when I try and find `TextInput` in my component it has a length of 0, even if I use `tree.dive().find('TextInput')`. Also, I'm using styled-components and if I try to console.log the html of `tree = shallow(
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <BareUserDetails {...props}/>
        </ThemeProvider>
      )` I receive `TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of undefined`.

Comment: Wanna move to a chat?

Comment: However, using `mount` gives me this error in the terminal: `Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a 'value' prop to a form field without an 'onChange' handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use 'defaultValue'. Otherwise, set either 'onChange' or 'readOnly'.`  (also, thank you for sticking with me so far! I appreciate the help)

Comment: replace `value` with `defaultValue`

Comment: yes, lets chat. It seems like I can't because my 'reputation' is low?

Comment: Oh shame! I don't know how else to help. How many points do you need to be able to chat?

Comment: Looks like twenty is needed. Argh! I'm trying to think of another way. I can create a slack channel but I'd need your email. Also, if I set value to defaultValue using an onChange would be useless then, no? How would I update my value to see if the event works as expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166973/discussion-between-dcodesmith-and-user8566336).